# Leaflet - Possible to go straight to node instead of popup on click?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the leaflet module in drupal and would like the user to go directly to the node instead of a popup when clicking upon a marker or polygon. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to use the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module, which works a treat! Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).
>
> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the most elegant way of achieving what I needed but it works until something better comes along. I modified a module called leaflet-views-ajax-popups in order to cannibalize the part of the code which gets the node id of the popup. Here's the replacment js;

```
 (function ($) {
 $(document).bind('leaflet.feature', function (event, lFeature, feature) {
 $(lFeature).click(function (e) {
  var data = {};
  for (var key in this._popup._contentNode.childNodes[0].attributes) {
    data[this._popup._contentNode.childNodes[0].attributes[key].name] =    this._popup._contentNode.childNodes[0].attributes[key].value;
 }    
    var mytaxid = data['data-id'];
    window.location = 'taxonomy/term/' + mytaxid ;        
 });
 });
 })(jQuery);
```

Still hoping someone can steer me to some simpler code.